# Partner() expected, got String()

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a course model and there is a many to many relationship with category, i am using a multi select on my form to get an array of objects, A course also can have a partner and the user can select this from a single select, but when i want to save to the database I call the params then I get a string instead of an object. not to sure how I can solve this

```
<%= form_for @course do |f| %>

<section class="new_course">
  <div class="row collapse">
    <div class="medium-5 small-centered column">     
      <%= f.label :course_title, :class=>"custom-prefix-class" %>
      <%= f.text_field :title, :autofocus => true, :class=>"custom-input-class" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row collapse">
    <div class="medium-5 small-centered column">     
      <%= f.label :start_date, :class=>"custom-prefix-class" %>
      <%= f.text_field :start_date, :class=>"custom-input-class" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-5  column with_chosen"> 
      <%= f.collection_select :categories,
      Category.all ,:id,:name,
      { include_blank: true},
      { class: 'chosen-select', :multiple=>true, :data => { :placeholder => ' ' }}
      %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-5  column"> 
      <%= f.collection_select :partner,
      Partner.all.collect, :id,:name ,
      { include_blank: true },
      { class: 'chosen-select', :multiple=>false, :data => { :placeholder => ' Brand Partner' }}
      %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In my controller

```
def create
  @course = Course.new(course_params)

  end
  if @course.save
    render :action=>'new'  
  end     
end

private
def course_params    
  params.require(:course).permit(:title, :start_date,:duration,:partner,:categories => [])
end
```

//rails server output

```
Started POST "/courses" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-07 16:45:28 +0200
Processing by CoursesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sKhAF2X6VOXTxZC9Pt51RFQfZSKdzXVWji6x4uwg+rI=", "course"=>{"title"=>"Marketing ", "start_date"=>"14-02-2014", "categories"=>["", "1", "2"], "partner"=>"1", "duration"=>"2-weeks"}, "commit"=>"Add new course"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Partner(#70274068591140) expected, got String(#70274066607160)):
  app/controllers/courses_controller.rb:24:in `create'
```

Comment: is partner a model?, and course has_one partner?

Comment: in you `course_params` have `:partner` key instead `:partner => []`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out:-

> it seems as that partner is a model and course has_one partner, so you
>   have to assign partner class object instead of id as string
>   actually as you can see in in question above value of

```
  params[:course][:partner] 
  => "1"
```

> is a string   now if you try to do something like   @course.partner
>   = '1'   it will raise an error like above, as on left hand side we have parter association and right and side a string.

just do this

```
def course_params    
  params.require(:course).permit(:title, :start_date,:duration,:partner,:categories => [])   
  if params[:course][:partner].present?
    params[:course][:partner] = Partner.find params[:course][:partner] 
  end
end
```

Comment: can you explaine last string

Comment: @Monk_Code last string?